# .NET Core web application with Popup modal. Can it move off screen to a new screen?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a .NET Core 5 web application.
Client side I am currently using Bootstrap modals.

I have a partial view that is just a button and when clicked we open a bootstrap modal.

So my users want this modal to go off screen.  So the Web application will be on one screen and the Modal is on another screen.

I don't think Bootstrap modals or ASP Views/Partial Views will do this.

Is there a way for a ASP .NET Core 5 web application to have a popup that will go offscreen from the web app?  Like when using 2 monitors

Thank you

Comment: They can open the web application on two tabs. Move one tab to the second monitor and open the modal there.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the default model popup will just inside one tab which inside the main page.

If you want this popup could move to the second screen, one possible way is using js to open this popup inside the new browser window.

For asp.net core MVC, you need write a new controller action or you need render the popup by yourself.

More details, you could refer to below easy sample:

Model popup view:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "ModelPopupContent";
}

<h1>Here is your new model popup codes</h1>
```

Main view:

```
<a id="openModalInNewWindow" href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-primary">Open Modal in New Tab</a>


@section Scripts{

    <script>
        document.getElementById("openModalInNewWindow").addEventListener("click", function () {
            var modalContentUrl = "@Url.Action("ModelPopupContent", "Home")"; // Replace "YourControllerName" with the actual controller name

            var modalWidth = 600; // Set the width of the modal content window
            var modalHeight = 400; // Set the height of the modal content window

            var left = (window.innerWidth - modalWidth) / 2;
            var top = (window.innerHeight - modalHeight) / 2;

            var newWindow = window.open(modalContentUrl, "_blank", "width=" + modalWidth + ", height=" + modalHeight + ", left=" + left + ", top=" + top);

            if (newWindow) {
                newWindow.focus();
            }
        });
    </script>
   
}
```

Result:

[image]